# AS3, change variable when "score" goes over set value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a little game with AS3, for fun. I've never tried AS3 before and barely been into AS2. I'm VERY new to coding and I've not really tried to learn anything. Just stepped right into it.

So, I'm trying to make a rank, where the first one is "Hobo", and as it hits, say 100 experience, the rank should change to "Recruit".

My idea was (And sorry if this is really bad, it's all very new to me), but it doesn't work.

```
var rank:String = "Hobo";
if (exp <= 100){
    rank = "Recruit";
}else if (exp <= 500){
    rank = "Member";
}else{
    trace("Not enough exp")
}
```

Again, I'm new to both AS3 and coding, so this might be very bad or COMPLETELY the wrong way to do this. I apologize.

Would be incredibly nice if someone could explain why this doesn't work, and the proper way to do this.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Please be more verbose than 'doesn't work'.    Right now,  the only way you'll get the message "Not enough exp" is if the exp is 501 or larger.  Probably not what you want.    If your `exp` is 100 or less, you'll get "Recruit",  if you exp is 101 - 500 you'll get member.     It's best to reverse the logic in these scenarios, start with the biggest threshold, and `else if` your way down to the lowest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
var rank:String = "Hobo";
if (exp >= 500){
    rank = "Member";
}else if (exp >= 100){
    rank = "Recruit";
}else{
    trace("Not enough exp")
}
```

Comment: Would you consider voting up my answer?